# Export form in php to text file

Tags: php

i have project to do.
i need to export from form to file text.
The project abotu photography web-site,there is section our customers can "buy" order by filling order form.
so what i want to do is to save the input from the order form.

Form

```
  <h3>Order</h3> 
<form action="shop.php" method="POST">
Order Number: <input type="text" name="Onumber"><br><br>
Product Name: <input type="text" name="product_name"><br><br>
Customer Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br><br>
Customer Number: <input type="text" name="Cnumber"><br><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br><br>
Phone Number: <input type="text" name="phone"><br><br>
Quantity: <input type="text" name="quantity"><br><br>
 <input type="submit" name="Add_order" value="Add order">
</form>
```

thats my try

```
if(isset($_POST['Onumber']) && isset($_POST['product_name'])&&isset($_POST['name'])&&isset($_POST['Cnumber'])&&isset($_POST['email'])&&isset($_POST['phone'])&&isset($_POST['quantity']) {
    $data = $_POST['Onumber'] . '-' . $_POST['product_name'] .$_POST['name'] . '-' . $_POST['Cnumber'] . $_POST['email'] . '-' . $_POST['phone'] . '-' . $_POST['quantity'] ."\n";
    $ret = file_put_contents('C:\ben\mydata.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    if($ret === false) {
        die('There was an error writing this file');
    }
    else {
        echo "$ret bytes written to file";
    }
}
else {
   die('no post data to process');
}
```

@PatrickQ now thats what i got: ---

```
  1234-GalLinder-1234lindergal@gmail.com-1239
    1234----
    1234-blabla-1234gal_124@walla.co.il-1234-1
    gf-gfdgf33-323232-34223-1


gdfgfdOrder Numberfgdfdsfd-fdsfdfdsfd-fsdfds-1


121212-PhotoLinder-147852lindergal@gmail.com-0544876117-1
```

and thats i want it to be:

```
order Number :1212
Product Name:Photo
Customer Name:Gal
E-mail:bla@gmail.com
Phone Number :0544876117
Quantity:1
---------------------------------
order Number :1213
Product Name:Photo
Customer Name:Gal
E-mail:bla@gmail.com
Phone Number :0544876117
Quantity:1
```

Comment: So what's your question?  You need to at least make some sort of attempt first.

Comment: @PatrickQ added in the main topic

Comment: And what is the problem with your approach? Looks similar to what I would have suggested.

Comment: Where did you get stuck?
Also, reduce your example code to as small snippet as possible still reproducing your problem. Probably having at least 7 fields  and saying "thank you" in code is not relevant to your problem.

Comment: On the txt file thats what iam getting  ---
1234-GalLinder-1234gal@gmail.com-1245   .thats what i wrote,but who can i do that with the lable text of the html?and how i can make order by order separated with ------------------

Comment: You should include an example of the exact desired result in your question.

Comment: @PatrickQ added in the main topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to automatically get the text that you're using next to your input fields.  You just have to hard-code that.

```
$data = "Order Number: " . $_POST['Onumber'] . "\n";
$data .= "Product Name: " . $_POST['product_name'] . "\n";
$data .= "Customer Name: " . $_POST['name'] . "\n";
$data .= "E-mail: " . $_POST['email'] . "\n";
$data .= "Phone Number: " . $_POST['phone'] . "\n";
$data .= "Quantity: " . $_POST['quantity'] ."\n";
$data .= "---------------------------------\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling your class correctly.

Change

```
 $db = new Order;
```

to

```
 $db = new Order();
```